# get a mutating url with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, microstrategy

i have the following question:

i'm currently working with a software(MicroStrategy, BI) wich has a functionality that exports reports to pdf, it works something like this:

each report has an unique ID, so you select the report to export, and with jsp i send this report's id to the exporting tool, and it generates a complete URL with some parameters that the MicroStrategy server will read to generate the PDF.

What i'm trying is to capture this pdf url and send it to a Java method that will save this pdf in the hard drive without prompting anything to the user.

My problem is that this URL doesn't generate instantly, it takes a while, AND, some redirections are made in the process.

So, after all that chitchat, how can i capture that damn URL?

What i'm doing is making the pdf load into an iframe, and then extracting the url with a js code i found searching, assigning it to a JSP variable, and then, once i have the pdf url, call the Java Method. But it is not working.

The JavaScript function is this:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function getSrc()
    {
        var CurrentUrl = document.getElementById('miframe').contentWindow.location.href;
        if(currentUrl.substr(length-5)==".pdf")
        {
           return currentUrl;
        }
        else
        {
           setTimeout(getSrc(),5000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is the call i make to it:

```
<% jsp code
    String currentUrl="<script>document.writeln(getSrc();)</script>";
more jsp code %>
```

The rest of the code is actually fine, tried it with a normal pdf URL and it saved the pdf into the disk.

Hope it is understadable, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are calling `getSrc`, not passing it to `setTimeout` (you are actually passing `null` to `setTimeout`, unless the second call to `getSrc` happens to work, in which case you are passing a string, which `setTimeout` can't process due to "syntax errors".

Instead, use `setTimeout(getSrc,5000);` - no parentheses after `getSrc`. This passes the function, rather than its result.

Also, `currentUrl.substr(length-5)` is wrong, partly because `length` is undefined (you need `currentUrl.length` in there), and partly because you need `-4` to get the last four characters.

Comment: Wow, that errors you point are totally noob ones. Don't know why i didn't pay more attention to the code D:

I think the call to getSrc() that you refer to is the one at the JSP code. Or is that wrong too? I think it isn't, but i'm not really sure

Comment: You were right , added an alert() and it never shows. How should i assing the return value of getSrc to the jsp String?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used JSP. I was just correcting your JS errors :p

Comment: Woops, sad face =(. Anyway, thanks, i could have done everything right, that it wouldnt work anyway! =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of access you have to MicroStrategy, but there is a MicroStrategy java api that will allow you to execute the document and get pdf without capturing the url.
Check out their Knowledge Base for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save the report/document with PDF format as default, in this way when you open the report it will automatically generated in PDF.

If you don't like the idea to save a report in PDF (for example because you need it also as regular report and you don't want to maintain two version of the same object), you can use URLAPI to generate the PDF using `&executionMode=3` and `&currentViewMedia=32`.

Not sure about these parameters, the best way for you to figure out which they are (beside some MicroStrategy TN) is to export the report in PDF and check the url.